# Populate Missing dates by month and Administrative Levels

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

I have a dataset that roughly looks like this:

```
     COUNTRY ADMIN1 month                YEAR nevent
   <chr>   <chr>  <dttm>              <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Algeria Adrar  2003-07-01 00:00:00  2003   1.00
 2 Algeria Adrar  2004-10-01 00:00:00  2004   1.00
 3 Algeria Adrar  2005-04-01 00:00:00  2005   1.00
 4 Algeria Adrar  2005-06-01 00:00:00  2005   1.00
 5 Algeria Adrar  2008-12-01 00:00:00  2008   1.00
 6 Algeria Adrar  2009-02-01 00:00:00  2009   1.00
 7 Algeria Adrar  2009-04-01 00:00:00  2009   2.00
 8 Algeria Adrar  2009-11-01 00:00:00  2009   1.00
 9 Algeria Adrar  2010-07-01 00:00:00  2010   1.00
10 Algeria Adrar  2012-02-01 00:00:00  2012   1.00
```

My units are monthly/1stadminlevel observations 
Now, my main problem is that this dataset is displaying just months/adminlevels and countries in Africa when the occurrence of certain events > 0. How can I populate observations with 0 observed events?

In other words I would need to add:
- every month when no event happened (n event= 0) 
- every admin1 where no events happened (ever and in specific months)
- every country where no events happened (ever and in specific months)

I notice the existence of the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
complete(dat, id, date)
```

But how can adapt it for particular my case?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `id`, you may need `COUNTRY` with `ADMIN1` along with `month`

Comment: Thus complete(aggregation, COUNTRY, ADMIN1, month)?

Comment: What about 'YEAR'.  You may need to show the expected

Comment: I launched: complete(aggregation, ADMIN1,COUNTRY,month, YEAR) but the resulting dataset has the same number of observations of the previous one.